# get Client IP in Amazon EC2 / Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to get Client IP using Laravel 5.2

It is not sensitive information, so I don't really care about IP Spoofing.

I tried this kind of scripts in my Model:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) {
    $clientIpAddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $clientIpAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

But When I run php artisan migrate, I get error

```
Undefined index: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR
```

or

```
Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR
```

But when I run:

```
<?php dd($_SERVER); ?>
```

I get

```
"SERVER_ADDR" => "10.0.1.194"
"REMOTE_PORT" => "38151"
"REMOTE_ADDR" => "201.141.124.254"
```

I don't understand !!!

Answer (score 0):

This is just because you running this in CLI (you use console to run migration).

PHP in CLI mode has another $_SERVER and has not REMOTE_ADDR key.

Comment: So what should be the fix?

Comment: Run this script in proper environment

Comment: I don't understand, what is proper env??? The only way I know to run migration is through ssh

Comment: Why you have this code in your migration ? The proper env is any web-server SAPI, where you can, for example, log client IP.

Comment: This code is in my User model, not in migration. I will try to move it to helper!

Comment: I moved it to helper, but I still get the error msg when running SEED! I didn't notice that. It make sense because in seeds, I create users